# Get multiple value from html with dom (without id or classes)

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get proxy and port value from this `http://jsbin.com/noxuqusoga/edit?html`, output html page.

Here is a sample of the table structure from that page, including only one `tr`, but the actual HTML has many `tr` elements with similar structure:

```
<table class="table" id="tbl_proxy_list" width="950">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-proxy-id="1355950">
            <td align="left"><abbr title="103.227.175.125">103.227.175.125 </abbr></td>
            <td align="left"><a href="/proxy-server-list/port-8080/" title="Port 8080 proxies">8080</a></td>
            <td align="left"><time class="icon icon-check timeago" datetime="2018-08-18 04:56:47Z">9 min ago</time></td>
            <td align="left">
            <div class="progress-bar" data-value="22" title="1089">
            <div class="progress-bar-inner" style="width:22%; background-color: hsl(26.4,100%,50%);">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <small>1089 ms</small></td>
            <td style="text-align:center !important;"><span style="color:#009900;">95%</span> <span> (94)</span></td>
            <td align="left"><img alt="sg" class="flag flag-sg" src="/assets/images/blank.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> <a href="/proxy-server-list/country-sg/" title="Proxies from Singapore">Singapore <span class="proxy-city"> - Bukit Timah </span> </a></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="proxy_transparent" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:10px;">Transparent</span></td>
            <td><span>-</span></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm able to scrap the proxy address but I have difficulties with the port as the `<td>` does not have an id or a class and as  value some have hyperlinks, and others don't.

How can I make the result like --> `ip:port` for the whole scrap result.

Here's my code

```
$html = file_get_html('http://jsbin.com/noxuqusoga/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('abbr') as $element)
       echo $element->title . '<br>';

foreach($html->find('td a') as $element)
       echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Use `DomNode->next_sibling` to get next `td` and `strip_tags` to strip `<a>` tags.

Comment: That does not look like DOM but a PHP library called `SimpleHTMLDOM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a selector for `td` elements (or elements inside them, like `abbr` or `a`) write a selector for their `tr` parent, then loop over these `tr`s (rows) and for each row, get the children of that row which you need:

```
// Select all tr elements inside tbody
foreach ($html->find('tbody tr') as $row)
    // the second parameter (zero) indicates we only need the first element matching our selector

    // ip is in the first <abbr> element that is child of a td
    $ip = $row->find('td abbr', 0)->plaintext;
    // port is in the first <a> element that is child of a td
    $port = $row->find('td a', 0)->plaintext;
    print "$ip:$port\n";
}
```

As an alternative, you should know when selecting elements, besides using css selectors you also have the option to get elements by their index. In your case, what you want from each `tr` is in the first and the second `td` elements inside each `tr` element. So you can also find the first and the second child of each `tr` to extract the data.